# Amazon webservices import not available com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have added the following dependencies still i am getting import error at
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context

I dont know what I am missing here.

```
    `<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.74</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.74</version>
    </dependency>`
```

I am using eclipse/maven for build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is a snapshot of the jar contents for the same:

[image: Jar Contents]

Comment: Did you find this useful?